# HTML list does not work in jsp file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sed

Working on a project with a html list inside a hidden div. For some reason the list is not working. The code sits in a .jsp file and the div is set to div `style='display:none'` if I copy the code to a html file then the list works.
Any insight on this is much appreciated.

```
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='the_div_id'>
<p style="text-align:left; padding-left:5px; color:#000000;">

                        <U>Text Header</U>
                        <BR>
                        <BR>
...text  

<a href="html_link_here" target="_new">Click Here</a> 
...text
<a href="html_link_here" target="_new">FAQ website</a>. 
                        <BR>
                        <BR>
...text
                        <BR>
                        <BR>
                        <hr>
                        <BR>
Text Header for List
                        <ul>
                            <li>text info</li>
                            <li>text info</li>
                            <li>text info</li>
                            <li>text info</li>
                            <li>text info</li>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>text</li>
                                    <li>text</li>
                                    <li>text</li>
                                    <li>text</li>
                                </ul>
                            <li>text</li>
                        </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: you meant tag `sad` instead of `sed`, didn't you?

Comment: `For some reason the list is not working.` - What do you mean it's not working... :/

Comment: Just in case anyone else has this issue, I have solved this by re defining the css at each horizontal rule. for some reason every time the code hits a HR the css needed to be re assigned with extra padding for the bullets to show inside the div.